# How to use latitude and longitude in a Zillow search url

Tags: url, zillow

When searching on Zillow using an address, the URL looks like this:

```
http://www.zillow.com/homes/{Street}", -"{City}," -"{State}" "{PostalCode}_rb/
```

However, there seems to be no documentation regarding the use of geographic coordinates in such a url.

How to use latitude and longitude instead of an address?

Answer (score 0):

<s>An answer in [Can I search Zillow using latitude and longitude coordinates? - Zillow Questions](http://www.zillow.com/advice-thread/Can-I-search-Zillow-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates/581068/) (the 1st Google result on "Zillow search by coordinates") dated 03.2015 gives an example:</s>

> http://www.zillow.com/homes/#/homes/for_sale/fsba,fsbo,new_lt/1_pnd/88.769211,-70.092773,-90,-158.686523_rect/3_zm/0_mmm/

Testing shows that only the `http://www.zillow.com/homes` and `/88.769211,-70.092773,-90,-158.686523_rect` parts are required.
It's `x0,y0,x1,y1` (the direction between the points can be any). <sub>(The coordinates in the example are quite strange and specify an area up to the North Pole. More realistic ones are e.g. `53.67068,-71.323242,13.453737,-127.045898_rect`.)</sub>
Since the last test, the technique stopped working. Moreover, coordinates appear to have vanished from property details as well!

There is no way provided to bring up a specific object by coordinates - they are instead uniquely identified by an ID (ZPID - Zillow Property ID) - and the way to bring up one as of now is e.g. `http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/7044216_zpid/`.

A possible reason is there's no way to guarantee that coordinates identify anything or identify something uniquely. I.e. coordinates are conceptually a search term rather than a means of identification.

Finally, do keep in mind that all this is undocumented and is subject to change (you can already see one quite-a-change above). They only support [API](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm) as the means to access their services programmatically.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

A URL of http://www.zillow.com/homes/88.769211,-70.092773,-90,-158.686523_rect   only brings up a map of Canada.  What step am I missing?

An example of a property I would like to locate via URL is:

Lat: 40.421776994149
Long: -74.148830107375

Comment: Please ignore the above comment!

Thanks so much for your help.

An example of a property I would like to locate via URL is:

Lat: 40.421776994149
Long: -74.148830107375

So, the URL would look like:

http://www.zillow.com/homes/40.421776994149,-74.148830107375,40.421776994149,-74.148830107375_rect  if I want to zero-in on the specific property, right?  Doing so does not result in anything.  What am I missing?

Comment: The coordinates are quite strange and, indeed, specify an area up to the North Pole. I only copied them from the example. More realistic ones are e.g. `53.67068,-71.323242,13.453737,-127.045898_rect`